# How to allow space with alpha numeric characters using keycode validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-objects, dom-events

This is the code below that only allows characters and numbers, but I want to allow space alongside characters and numbers. Please help.

```
function IsAlphaNumericTour(e) {
      var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
      var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));
      document.getElementById("error_tour").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
      return ret;
 }
```

Comment: Just add the keyCode of the space

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add the keyCode of (space) into this function

```
function IsAlphaNumericTour(e) {
      var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
      var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || keyCode == 32 ||(specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));
      document.getElementById("error_tour").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
      return ret;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The key code for space is 32, so you'd change your conditional to something like this:

```
var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode) || keyCode == 32);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like, you can also do this with a regular expression test:

```
function IsAlphaNumericTour(e) {
  var key = e.which;
  var regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9 ]/;
  var ret = key.test(regex);
  // This method returns true if it finds a match, otherwise it returns false.
  $("#error_tour").css("display", (ret ? "none" : "inline"));
  return ret;
}
```